# Stop Navigation Menu from Spanning 2 lines

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I am working on this site and in IE the nav menu spans 2 lines:
http://www.sandiegolawfirm.com/

I would like to either remove the space on the left of bankruptcy or reduce the font size by a point or two in IE. Allowing all the departments to fit on one nav menu line.

I am actively trying to fix this but would appreciate help with figuring out the best way to get this done.

Thanks - Raleigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way fix changes specific to use styles that are specific to IE. Depending on which version you're trying to fix for there are different rules you can use.

For example:

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
#any rules you like
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
#any rules you like
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
#any rules you like
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
#any rules you like
<![endif]-->
```

There's a tutorial here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Thanks that's helpful but I already have an ie.css stylesheet but I am having a hard time finding the property to edit that does what I described above.

Comment: From inspect element, it looks like you can apply the changes to the following selectors:

.menu-primary li.current_page_item a, 
.menu-primary li.current-cat a, 
.menu-primary li.current-menu-item a, 
.menu-primary li.current-page-parent a { font-size: xxxx }

You can make the change inside your ie.css file

Comment: I was able to fix it on my own by reducing the font size to 15px in IE only. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding something like

```
ul li:first-of-type a{
   margin-left:-20px;
}
```

to the IE styles could work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use custom fonts and getting unpredictable results in IE since "Gotham" isn't available. You could try using a Google webfont or upload a webfont to your server to at least get similar font sizes.